# $(\vec Ae^{kt} + \vec Be^{-kt})\times (\vec Ae^{kt} - \vec Be^{-kt})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How do I evaluate this cross product? $$(\vec Ae^{kt} + \vec Be^{-kt})\times (\vec Ae^{kt} - \vec Be^{-kt})$$ where $\vec A, \vec B$ are constant vectors and $k, s$ are constant scalars.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) are some latex tips. Also, you should write exactly what your question is and what prevents you from answering it on your own. While you're editing your post to make it intelligible, remember that mathematic notation is case-sensitive.

Comment: to simplify, just call $\vec{A}e^{kt} = \vec{C}$ say, and then $\vec{B}e^{-kt} = \vec{D}$. Then you call the sum and the difference of these two vectors say $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{F}$. At this point you simply do the cross product and by evaluating it and substituting, you'll see a lot of stuff cancels out

Comment: with my relabelling, you should get something like $-2c_2d_3\vec{i} + 2c_1d_3\vec{j}-2c_1d_2\vec{k}$ , where $\vec{C} = (c_1,c_2,c_3)$ and $\vec{D} = (d_1,d_2,d_3)$

Answer (score 1):

By expansion, knowing that $\vec{A} \times \vec{A}=\vec{B} \times \vec{B}=0$, it is

$$-\vec{A} \times \vec{B} + \vec{B} \times \vec{A}=-2\vec{A} \times \vec{B}.$$

Remark: you mention in your question a variable $s$ that is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Call $\vec{A}e^{kt} = \vec{C}$ say, and  $\vec{B}e^{-kt} = \vec{D}$. Then call the sum and the difference of these two vectors say $\vec{E} = \vec{C} + \vec{D}$ and $\vec{F} = \vec{C}-\vec{D}$. By doing the cross product and substituting you get $-2c_2d_3\vec{i} + 2c_1d_3\vec{j}-2c_1d_2\vec{k}$ , where $\vec{C} = (c_1,c_2,c_3)$ and $\vec{D} = (d_1,d_2,d_3)$.

At this point, substitute, giving a labelling such as $\vec{A} = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $\vec{B} = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and you'll find the answer. Remember that you'll have to multiply by the exponentials.

For instance $c_1 = a_1e^{kt} + b_1e^{-kt}$ and $d_3 = a_3e^{kt} - b_3e^{-kt}$

So that the $i$-th component will be $-2(a_1e^{kt} + b_1e^{-kt})(a_3e^{kt} - b_3e^{-kt})= -2 ( a_1a_3e^{2kt} - a_1b_3+b_1a_3-b_1b_3e^{-2kt})$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
(\vec Ae^{kt} + \vec Be^{-kt})\times (\vec Ae^{kt} - \vec Be^{-kt})&=\color{blue}{(\vec Ae^{kt} + \vec Be^{-kt})\times (\vec Ae^{kt} + \vec Be^{-kt})}\\\\
&-\color{red}{2(\vec Ae^{kt} + \vec Be^{-kt})\times (\vec Be^{-kt})}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{0}-\color{red}{2(\vec A\times\vec B)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark